# What does $\{0,1\}*\mathbb{N}$ mean?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The question is to define a bijection 
$$ f: \{0,1\}*\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N} $$
I can't interpret what does $\{0,1\}*\mathbb{N}$ mean?

Q. Two sets $P$ and $Q$ are given. Question is to define bijection from $P \rightarrow Q$

[image]

Comment: What question ?

Comment: I think it means the direct product. Probably the symbol you want to use is $\times$. Ignore if incorrect.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Question edited, please see the attached image, that's how the question is given. Looks like a * to me. Not sure

Comment: Ok, this is a little odd, it definitely is a $*$. If you are using a pdf file from which you are deriving these definitions, can you attach the pdf file above, or show me the link?

Comment: Sure. It is Question 2, part c

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг It is indeed the direct product, I guess it is a printing mistake. The solution given to me also makes sense now. In the solution they defined a function $f(x,y)$.

Comment: Even from the questions after the aforementioned one, we see that clearly, $*$ is used to represent the direct product, which should ideally be with a $\times$. So that's what it means, the direct product. However, knowing that it is the direct product now, can you do the question?

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Yup now the question is solvable.

Comment: That's good. Since this question is now answered, I request you to close it. This can be done by posting your own answer and accepting it (you can call me to verify).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the symbol was just a printing mistake it is the direct product symbol. Now the function can be defined as
$$ f(x,y) = \begin{cases} 2y &\mbox{if } x = 0 \\ 
2y - 1 & \mbox{if } x = 1 \end{cases} $$
Can easily be seen that it is bijective.

Comment: Perfect. I upvote. Once you are allowed to do so, accept it.